# Accessing a file behind Cloudflare protection using Power Query / Get & Transform in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, cloudflare

I have a series of data connections in an Excel spreadsheet to retrieve information from the URL below. The file it points to is a public dataset of inflation data from the Reserve Bank of New Zealand (RBNZ).

Recently, the RBNZ website started using Cloudflare protection, which has broken all of my queries.

I tried my backup tactic, which is downloading the file via VBA using, but I run into the same problem - the connection fails the Cloudflare test, and returns an error *or* just downloads the "Cloudflare is checking your browser" HTML.

I've had to resort to my *backup* backup option, which is scripting to open an Internet Explorer window, and using SendKeys to get the file. Obviously, I would prefer **not** to have to do that.

I guess this is exactly the kind of automation that Cloudflare is trying to block, so I'm not very hopeful, but if anyone has any ideas, I would be incredibly grateful.

https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/-/media/ReserveBank/Files/Statistics/Key%20graphs/graphdata.xlsx

Comment: What is the website link rather than the direct file link? Was it this one: https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/statistics/key-graphs/key-graph-inflation

Comment: I'm off to work but this looks like at some point might be the way if they include your dataset: https://www.stats.govt.nz/experimental/stats-nz-open-data-api   This sounds like fairly readily available data so I would be surprised if there isn't an alternative source.

Comment: Yes, sorry - that's the base URL. 

I hadn't actually considered Stats NZ's API, to be honest. I haven't looked at it in a while, but I was under the impression it was quite general stuff, rather than the macroeconomic indicators. I'll take a proper look and see what materializes.

Comment: I think you are prolly right from the quick scan I did this morning but these figures I would expect to see available from another source surely? Via an API hopefully.

Comment: You'd definitely think so, but so far, many hours of Googling has turned up nothing :/